# Which shape is next in the sequence?

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

This picture has been driving me crazy all day. [image]

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer is:

> **B**

Because:

> The first shape has 4 closed areas in it.
>  The second has 5 closed areas in it.
>  The third has 1 closed area in it.
>  The fourth has 2 closed areas in it.
>  The fifth has 3 closed areas in it.

So:

> The next shape should have 4 such areas.
> Here are the closed areas I'm talking about:
>  [image: Image representation of the areas]
>  **Note:** The sequence is `4 5 1 2 3` and not `1 2 3 4 5` is probably to show that it is an infinite looping sequence `... 4 5 1 2 ...`, and to obscure it a bit so it is not too obvious.

Comment: Too many upvotes for your answer, which makes me think I'm missing something, I couldn't figured out yet.

Comment: @newzad Is my answer not clear? Should I explain it more?